# drupal 7 Ubercart recurring fee settings tab is blank

Tags: ubercart

I get an error
on my screen There are no payment methods configured for orders with recurring fees, enable one from recurring fee admin settings.

I then go to the link
cart/checkout#overlay=admin/store/settings/products/edit/features

Next i try and choose the Reccuring fee settings tab but it is completely blank.

Version of UC Recurring Payments and Subscriptions module is 7.x-2.0-alpha3

I am wondering if down grade will that fix the problem.

Comment: have you found any solution? In some users it does not display but for some of them it displays fine for me. I am in particular talking about recurring-fees

Answer (score 1):

You may have to enable the module "Recurring - Hosted Gateways". This should be available under section "UBERCART - RECURRING" in the path admin/modules. In my case this is Paypal WPS.

Once the module is enabled you can see the option at admin/store/settings/recurring. You may also need to enable the required payment methods at admin/store/settings/payment.

Answer (score -2):

You can find the configuration under 'admin/store/settings/recurring'

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers.  What setting should @Alexander check or set on this page to address the problem?